# how to inner join in nested table

Tags: mysql

im a newbe, i want to inner join from 4 table. its table in MySql.

```
++model_table++
id_model
name_model

++vendor_table++
id_vendor
name_vendor

++detail_table++
id_detail
id_model

++hanca_table++
id_hanca
id_detail
id_vendor
```

how to innerjoin showing name_model name_vendor from hanca_table ?

i try this query =

```
SELECT model_table.name_model, vendor_table.name_vendor 
FROM hanca 
INNER JOIN model_table ON model_table.id_model = ????
```

Answer (score 0):

Already so many inner join questions are there.You may refer them.
  Any way try this:

```
select mod.name_model,ven.name_vendor from hance han 
    inner join detail det on han.id_detail = det.id_detail
    inner join model mod on mod.id_model = det.id_model
    inner join vendor ven on han.id_vendor = ven.id_vendor
```